# How to insert a top bar to a full page iframe

Tags: css, iframe, css-position

I want to make a page which shows:

- A top bar
- A full page iframe (but for the top bar)

I am translating this to something like this:

```
<div id="topbar">bla bla bla</div>
<iframe src="http://www.ign.es/iberpix2/visor/" style="width:100%; height:100%;"</iframe>
```

However the problem is that the height is 100% of navigator height, and with the "topbar" the real size exceeds 100%.

Is it possible to make what I am looking for? This is, to match the iframe height to 100% of the REMAINING page height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve my problem.

The key was adding `margin: 0px; padding: 0px;` to `<body>` and using `calc(100% - 30px)` for the second `<div>`.

```
<body style="height:100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <div style="height:30px; background-color: #B0CCB0">Hola.</div>
    <div style="height: calc(100% - 30px); background-color:red">
        <iframe src="http://www.ign.es/iberpix2/visor/" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%; border:none;">Tu navegador no soporta iframes, accede directamente a la herramienta <a href="http://www.ign.es/iberpix2/visor/">IBERPIX</a>.</iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

Great!

Answer (score 3):

In the Snippet the `.topBar` and `.frame` are wrapped in `.box`. `.topBar` has a red border and `.frame` has a blue border which demonstrates they both co-exist within 100% of height. Among all of the styles, the one most relevant is:

```
height: calc(100% - 40px);
```

The 40px is the height I arbitrarily gave to `.topBar`.

Also these properties and unit measures as well:

- [`position`](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)
- [`vw` and `vh`](http://thenewcode.com/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design)
- [`overflow-x` and `overflow-y`](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html)

## SNIPPET

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font: 400px 16px/1.428 Consolas;
}
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.box {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}
.topBar {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.frame {
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid blue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>topBar</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <div class="box">

    <header class='topBar'>topBar</header>

    <iframe src="https://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/" class='frame' frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>

  </div>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to close <head> and open <body>